# Docker port forwarding: connection timed out

Tags: docker, portforwarding

I'm using the `nginx:alpine` Docker image, running it like so:

`c@makina ~> docker run -itp 8000:80 nginx:alpine`

The port is shown as listening in lsof:

`c@makina ~> sudo lsof -i :8000
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 3653 root    4u  IPv4 2025067      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)`

However, when trying to access it, I get a connection timeout:

`c@makina ~> http :8000
http: error: Request timed out (30s).`

Starting another container with a link to the nginx container lets me access it, however:

`c@makina ~> docker run -it --link ${CONTAINER_ID}:nginx alpine:3.6 /bin/sh
/ # curl -s -D - -o /dev/null http://nginx/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...`

The docker0 bridge (and the br-* bridge and veth* interfaces) are up on the host, and both lo and eth0 are up in the nginx container.

The firewall is disabled on the host:

`root@makina /h/c# service iptables status
 * status: stopped`

Any ideas?

Comment: did you tried accessing http://192.168.99.100:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue was that the loopback interface was not up. Adding it to `/etc/network/interfaces` and running `ifup lo` fixed the issue.